# Extract words containing question marks

Tags: regex

I have tens of long text files (10k - 100k record each) where some characters were lost by careless handling and got replaced with question marks. I need to build a list of corrupted words.

I'm sure the most effective approach would be to regex the file with sed or awk or some other bash tools, but I'm unable to compose regex that would do the trick.

Here are couple of sample records for processing:

```
?ilkin, Aleksandr, Zahhar, isa
?igadlo-?van, Maria, Karl, abikaasa, 27.10.45, Veli?anõ raj.
```

Desired output would be:

```
?ilkin
?igadlo-?van
Veli?anõ
```

My best result so far seems to retrieve only words from the beginning of records:

```
awk '$1 ~/\?/ {print $1}' test.txt
```

->

```
?ilkin,
?igadlo-?van,
```

Comment: What are you planning on using? Python, Java etc. Please try to make some code yourself and then ask for direct questions. For example errors which may occur.

Comment: Actually I'm ready to use whatever works.
I would expect some simple bash tools but will appreciate perl/node/python

Comment: Please, first try to write some code. Can't do all the work for you.

Comment: you can do it in notepad++ - open your file and do search, it supports regex search as well

Comment: for regex https://regex101.com is good place to look at

Comment: and by the way characters are not corrupted, but replaced by ? because wrong localization used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to build a list of corrupted words

If the aim is to only search for matches `grep` would be the most fast and powerful tool:

```
grep -Po '(^|)([^?\s]*?\?[^\s,]*?)(?=\s|,|$)' test.txt
```

The output:

```
?ilkin
?igadlo-?van
Veli?anõ
```

---

*Explanation*:

`-P` option, allows ***perl*** regular expresssions

`-o` option, tells to print only matched substrings

`(^|)` - matches the start of the string or an empty value(we can't use word boundary anchor `\b` in this case cause question mark `?` is considered as a word boundary)

`[^?\s]*?` - matches any character except `?` and whitespace `\s` if occurs

`\?[^\s,]*?` - matches a question mark `?` followed by any character except whitespace `\s` and `,`(which can be at right word boundary)

`(?=\s|,|$)` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that a needed substring is followed by either whitespace `\s`, comma `,` or placed at the end of the string

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I really admire the regex ability some people possess. May I thank you once more :)